# Parsing Beautiful Soup through the list of url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to **scrape** all headlines on autism topic from Le Monde newspaper's archive (from 1980).
I'm not a programmer but humanitarian who is trying to be "digital"...

I managed to get a list of all (daily) issues and, from another side, parsing with soup a one url at time and extract headlines works as well. But both together don't.
I fill my problem is on the parsing+iteration step but am not able to solve it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = date(2018, 1, 1)
end = date.today()
all_url =[]

#this chunk is working and returns a nice list of all url of all issues
day = timedelta(days=1)
one_url = "https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/"
mydate = start

while mydate < end:
    mydate += day
    if one_url not in all_url:
        all_url.append(one_url + "{date.day:02}/{date.month:02}/{date.year}".format(date=mydate) + '/')

#this function is working as well when applied with one single url
def titles(all_url):
    
    for url in all_url:
        page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
        
        regexp = re.compile(r'^.*\b(autisme|Autisme)\b.*$')
        
        for headlines in page.find_all("h3"):
            h = headlines.text
        
            for m in regexp.finditer(h):
                print(m.group())
        
titles(all_url)
```

This script is just stuck...

Comment: The start date in this code is the beginning of 2018 so as to try facilitate to run...

Comment: The script is going to take a while to run, it is not stuck. You can add a `print` inside the `title` function's outer loop in order to check if it is still running. I did notice however that Le Monde seems to use urls terminated with dates in the format `01-01-2018` for its archive, so changing the separators there might help.

Comment: I just ran the script for all the days from last year to today (496 urls), it took almost 5 minutes on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The script is not stuck. I have added print statements so that you could visualize that it is working. But initially I thought may the issue is in your regex pattern.

When I actually opened one of that web link (https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/25/03/2018/), the server responded with 404 as this page does not exist on server. [image]
Since you have created page urls with code so it is highly likely that those link correspond to none on server side.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = date(2018, 1, 1)
end = date.today()
all_url =[]

#this chunk is working and returns a nice list of all url of all issues
day = timedelta(days=1)
one_url = "https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/"
mydate = start

while mydate < end:
    mydate += day
    if one_url not in all_url:
        all_url.append(one_url + "{date.day:02}/{date.month:02}/{date.year}".format(date=mydate) + '/')

#this function is working as well when applied with one single url
def titles(all_url):

    counter = 0
    for url in all_url:
        print("[+] (" + str(counter) + ") Fetching URL " + url)
        counter += 1
        page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

        regexp = re.compile(r'^.*\b(autisme|Autisme)\b.*$')

        found = False
        for headlines in page.find_all("h3"):
            h = headlines.text

            for m in regexp.finditer(h):
                found = True
                print(m.group())

        if not found:
            print("[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....")
            print()

titles(all_url)
```

Script Output:

```
[+] (0) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/02/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (1) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/03/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (2) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/04/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (3) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/05/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (4) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/06/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (5) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/07/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (6) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/08/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (7) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/09/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (8) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/10/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (9) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/11/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....

[+] (10) Fetching URL https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/12/01/2018/
[-] Can't Find any thing relevant this page....
```

You can see each url by inspecting in web browsers. Kindly let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the date format used in Le Monde's archive urls is `day-month-year`, not `day/month/year`. To fix it change:

```
all_url.append(one_url + "{date.day:02}/{date.month:02}/{date.year}".format(date=mydate) + '/')
```

to

```
all_url.append(one_url + "{date.day:02}-{date.month:02}-{date.year}".format(date=mydate) + '/')
```

The feeling that the program is stuck is simply due to lack of feedback. [@Zaid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56102083/3044673) shows how to solve that in an elegant manner.

If you need a more speedy approach to making a bunch of HTTP requests you should consider using something asynchronous. I suggest using [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/), which is a framework built for this kind of task (web scraping).

I made a simple spider to fetch all of the headlines containing `'autism'` in the archive (from the beginning of 2018 to today):

```
import re
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

import scrapy

BASE_URL = 'https://www.lemonde.fr/archives-du-monde/'


def date_range(start, stop):
    for d in range((stop - start).days):
        yield start + timedelta(days=d)


class LeMonde(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'LeMonde'

    def start_requests(self):
        for day in date_range(date(2018, 1, 1), date.today()):
            url = BASE_URL + '{d.day:02}-{d.month:02}-{d.year}'.format(d=day) + '/'
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        for headline in response.xpath('//h3/a/text()').getall():
            headline = headline.strip()

            if 'autism' in headline.lower():
                yield { 'headline': headline }
```

I was able to scrape the headlines in 47 seconds using the above code. If you are interested, you may run it with:

```
scrapy runspider spider_file.py -o headlines.csv
```

this will generate a csv file (`headlines.csv`) containing the headlines.

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed, I was wrong with date's format: well seen! Thanks as well for this chunk of Scrapy code which seems to be so easy... I saw there is Scrapy as solution but understood it's much more tough (than Beautiful Soup). Now will dare try it!

Comment: bla, just by chance...what Scrapy version do you use? I downloaded 1.6.0 and can't run your script as it doesn't find some modules ("twisted" for instance).

Comment: I used scrapy 1.6.0 with python 3.7.3. That is strange... How did you install scrapy? Twisted should be installed as its dependency.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I installed by pip. And from Jupyter-notebook doesn't work neither...Wonder if there is any intreference with anaconda.

Comment: Does `pip freeze` list `Twisted`? If it doesn't you may want to try and reinstall scrapy. [This page](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) has more information regarding scrapy installation, it may also help.

Comment: According to the installation docs you can install scrapy from the `conda-forge` channel using `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`. I hope it helps. I have no experience with anaconda at all, :(.

Comment: pip freeze lists Twisted==19.2.0; when run on IDLE the Shell shows the next:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/CS6507/scrapy.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scrapy
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/CS6507/scrapy/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import _monkeypatches
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/CS6507/scrapy/_monkeypatches.py", line 20, in <module>
    import twisted.persisted.styles  # NOQA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted'  May be it's because I use Python 3.7.0b4?

Comment: It looks like some other people had similar problems. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772381/importerror-no-module-named-twisted-persisted-styles) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763614/installing-twisted-through-pip-broken-on-one-server) questions.