# Django Channels pip install fails

Tags: django, centos7, channel

When running pip install -U channels command on Centos7 I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted>=17.5 (from daphne~=2.2->channels) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for twisted>=17.5 (from daphne~=2.2->channels)
```

I have a virtual env in my localhost and I am trying  to install all dependancies from my requirements.txt file. pip freeze gives the following output:

```
aioredis==1.1.0
asgiref==2.3.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
async-timeout==2.0.1
attrs==17.4.0
autobahn==18.4.1
Automat==0.6.0
cffi==1.11.5
configparser==3.5.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.2.2
Django==2.0.2
django-bootstrap3==9.1.0
django-modalview==0.1.5
h2==3.0.1
hiredis==0.2.0
hpack==3.0.0
hyperframe==5.1.0
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.6
incremental==17.5.0
msgpack==0.5.6
msgpack-python==0.5.6
Pillow==5.0.0
priority==1.3.0
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycparser==2.18
PyMySQL==0.8.1
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pytz==2018.3
redis==2.10.6
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.11.0
txaio==2.10.0
zope.interface==4.4.3
```

Comment: What is your pip version, did you try `pip install pip -U`

Comment: Could you post  which is python version in question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are using python 3.5+ as the channels v2 package requires python version 3.5+ to run.

I was having the same issue on Centos7 and a local install of python3.6 that I had compiled from source. In turns out that I didn't have the bz2 library package installed.
Here is the answer that led me to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766325/6581384

I just had to replace the first command in that answer with the following for centos 7:

`$ sudo yum install bzip2 bzip2-libs bzip2-devel`